# Dagger/MissingBinding but module exists

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2, dagger-hilt

I'm trying to put dagger into my project and I'm facing a compilation issue I don't get since I've done everything like the android developer tutorial. I get:

> error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] INotificationService cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method

Here is my app annotation:

```
@HiltAndroidApp
class App : MultiDexApplication() {
```

Activity annotation:

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity: AppCompatActivity() {
```

Fragment annotation:

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class NotificationFragment: Fragment(R.layout.fragment_notification) {
```

I think everything's ok until there. Then the problem I'm facing is here:

Viewmodel class:

```
@HiltViewModel
class NotificationViewModel @Inject constructor(private val notificationService: INotificationService): ViewModel()
```

Here is the interface for INotificationService:

```
interface INotificationService {
    fun refreshNotification(): Single<List<INotification>>
    fun markAsRead(notification: INotification)
}
```

and the implementation:

```
class NotificationServiceImpl @Inject constructor(@ApplicationContext context: Context): INotificationService
```

with associated module:

```
@Module
@InstallIn(ActivityComponent::class)
abstract class NotificationModule {
    @Binds
    abstract fun bindNotificationService(impl: NotificationServiceImpl): INotificationService
}
```

The bindNotificationService binds function from the module is greyed out, it's not the case on the android developer tutorial and the error makes me think I missed something to make this function findable at compile time but since there is @Module and @InstallIn(ActivityComponent::class) I have absolutly no idea why it doesn't compile.

Comment: you should use `@InstallIn(ViewModelComponent::class)`

Comment: @IR42 thanks a lot. I didn't check all these component class and though that since the viewmodel is used inside an activity it was ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

INotificationService is ViewModel dependency and it should bind with ViewModel lifecycle so instead of this

```
@Module
@InstallIn(ActivityComponent::class)
abstract class NotificationModule {
    @Binds
    abstract fun bindNotificationService(impl: NotificationServiceImpl): INotificationService
}
```

Use this:-

```
@Module
@InstallIn(ViewModelComponent::class)
abstract class NotificationModule {
    @Binds
    abstract fun bindNotificationService(impl: NotificationServiceImpl): INotificationService
}
```